# How to handle squashfs in Windows

Tags: python-2.7, squashfs

I have to update some files in a squashfs image file. I found a tool in Linux but not in Windows.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 10):

[7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) is capable of opening squashfs images and extracting their files. I tested this on 7-Zip version 15.14 [64-bit] on Windows 10 with a squashfs image which uses xz compression.

7-Zip does not appear to list squashfs among the archive formats when creating an archive, so you'll need to look elsewhere if you want to generate a squashfs image with modified files. The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) for squashfs indicates that mksquashfs and unsquashfs have been ported to some versions of Windows (it also mentions 7-Zip).

[André's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47373036/5384908) suggests Cygwin as a way to compile and run commands from `squashfs-tools`. The [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install-win10) provides another way to run `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs`. On my Windows 10 system in which `Ubuntu 14.04.4` is running via WSL, the following command installed `squashfs-tools`, after which `mksquashfs` and `unsquashfs` are available.

```
sudo apt install squashfs-tools
```

With either approach to using `squashfs-tools` (Cygwin or WSL), 7-Zip is unnecessary for updating files in a squashfs image.

Comment: Squashfs-tools can be used natively: https://github.com/AgentD/squashfs-tools-ng

Answer (score 10):

Eirik's answer solved the "unzip" part. I'll give you the entire **squashfs-tools** in Windows, so you can both "unzip" (`unsquashfs.exe`) and "zip" (`mksquashfs.exe`).

1. Get [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html) if you don't have it.
2. Install the following Cygwin packages:

   - If you're running 32-bit:

     - `gcc-core`
     - `cygwin64-gcc-core`
   - If you're running 64-bit:

     - `gcc-core`
     - `cygwin32-gcc-core`
   - `xz`
   - `liblzma5` (not sure this is needed)
   - `liblzma-devel`
3. Get the [latest squashfs source](https://sourceforge.net/projects/squashfs/files/latest/download?source=files).
4. Uncomment the following lines in `squashfs-tools/Makefile`:

   - `XZ_SUPPORT = 1`
   - `LZMA_XZ_SUPPORT = 1`
5. In a Cygwin console, go to the `squashfs-tools` directory and compile with:

<sub>*copy-paste this*</sub>

```
make EXTRA_CFLAGS="-Dlinux -DFNM_EXTMATCH='(1<<5)' -D'sigtimedwait(a,b,c)=sigwaitinfo(a,b)'"
```

6. Install with good old `make install`

Now you have the squashfs tools in a Cygwin command line just like if it was Linux. As stated above, the tools are `unsquashfs.exe` and `mksquashfs.exe`.

---

**Source and credits of this answer:** http://domoticx.com/bestandssysteem-squashfs-tools-software/ (Dutch, I used Google Translate)

Comment: Should it not be `cygwin64-gcc-core` for 64 bit systems and vice versa?
update: `cygwin64-gcc-core` does not seem to exist on apt-cyg

Comment: The build of squashfs-tools failed :/

Comment: For me version of sources from SourceForge doesn't compile anymore, has compile errors. But version from [GitHub here](https://github.com/plougher/squashfs-tools) compiled successfully with same steps.

Comment: @ArraysStartAt1 please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33203075/4850 to understand why the package names are correct the way I wrote them

Comment: You will also need to install the 'make' package from cygwin for this to work.